# Can an inherited method call an overriding method instead of the original?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Imagine the following situation, where an inherited method that calls a method of the superclass must call a method of the child class instead:

```
// super.java

public class Processor {
   public void process(String path) {
      File file = new File(path);

      // some code
      // ...

      processFile(file);
   }
   protected void processFile(File file) {
      // some code
      // ...

      reportAction(file.name());
   }
   protected void reportAction(String path) {
      System.out.println("processing: " + path);
   }
}
```

---

```
// child.java

public class BatchProcessor extends Processor {
   public void process(String path) {
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] contents = folder.listFiles();
      int i;

      // some code
      // ...

      for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) super.processFile(file);
   }
   protected void reportAction(String path) {
      System.out.println("batch processing: " + path);
   }
}
```

Obviously, the code presented above doesn't work as it should. The class `BatchProcessor` prints `"processing: <file>"` instead of `"batch processing: <file>"` as it calls the method from the superclass instead of the new one. Is there any way to overcome this obstacle?

Thanks in Advance! :D

Comment: With the code you put there, you will always get "batch processing: <file>" printed. What is the problem again ?

Comment: Please, read it carefully. I always get `"processing: <file>"`. I want to get `"batch processing: file"` when I call the `process` method of the `BatchProcessor` and `"processing: <file>"` when I call the same function from the `Processor` class.

Comment: Can you please post code showing how you call these methods ?

Comment: Of course...
`Processor processor = new Processor();
processor.process(file);` and 
`BatchProcessor batchprocessor = new BatchProcessor();
batchProcessor.process(folder);`
Both calls are located in the classes' `main` functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
processor.process("filePath"); // will print "processing: <file>"
// and 
Processor batchProcessor = new BatchProcessor();
batchProcessor.process("filePath"); // will print "batch processing: <file>"
```

this is how polymorphic methods work. I guess you are just not calling `processor` on subclass instance ?

**edit**
Please run the following code for a quick proof for yourself:

```
class Parent {
    void test() {
        subTest();
    }

    void subTest() {
        System.out.println("subTest parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void subTest() {
        System.out.println("subTest Child");
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Child().test(); // prints "subTest Child"
    }
}
```

Here is what happens when you call `superClass` `processFile` method on your `subClass` instance: 
your `this` reference across this call will refer to your `subClass` instance, always resulting in polymorphic call of `subClass`'s methods if they are overriden.

Comment: I think this will for sure always call the super methods... :(
That's exactly the opposite of what I am looking for.

Comment: @angel No, this will for sure call subclass methods. BTW, you could add `@Override` notation to each of your `BatchProcessor` methods declaration to make sure they are really overriden

Comment: But you "see" `batchProcessor` as a simple `Processor` class. This means that you will call the original `process` method and thus the original `reportAction` too. As about `@Override`, can you elaborate? Thanks...

Comment: Oh god, what an idiot I am! The problem lies in main... The main is also inherited from the super class and thus uses `Processor processor = new Processor()`. +1 for your answer; any ideas, however? ;)

Comment: @angel main method is supposed to be declared `static`, in which case it can not be inherited.

Comment: @angel I need to put my kid to sleep now, come back in 40 mins if you still need help. Sorry, but she can't wait anymore... : (

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40436/discussion-between-kiruwka-and-angel)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove reportAction() from processFile() and call it separately if likely to change:

```
// super.java

public class Processor {
   public void process(String path) {
      File file = new File(path);

      // some code
      // ...

      processFile(file);
      reportAction(file.name());


   }
   protected void processFile(File file) {
      // some code
      // ...

   }
   protected void reportAction(String path) {
      System.out.println("processing: " + path);
   }
}


// child.java

public class BatchProcessor extends Processor {
   public void process(String path) {
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] contents = folder.listFiles();
      int i;

      // some code
      // ...

      for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) 
      {
          super.processFile(file);
          reportAction(file.name());
       } 
   }
   protected void reportAction(String path) {
      System.out.println("batch processing: " + path);
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean there is no way for the super method to call an overriding method, if invoked from the child?